# How to add id atribute to all html tags that have only name tag

Tags: jsp

An example of what I need to do is:

<INPUT name="input1"> should have and id attribute <input name="input1" id="input1">.

All HTML elements having the NAME attribute should also have an ID attribute if they don't already have it.

How can I achieve this? Tried using regex but HTML is not well-formatted so it didn't work, I'm thinking about parsing all JSP files, adding an ID to elements that don't have it, and overwriting the original JSP file.

PS: Need to move an old app from IE5 to IE11 or edge. In IE5 getElementById works fine if the field has only name attribute but in the latest version of IE that is not the case.

Answer (score 0):

Will use Jsoup, this awesome lib parses even jsp-s after minor adjustments. Had to comment out directives and <% %>